Service Worker doesn't work with Socket.io event
I'm trying to pass a 'ping' from the client to the server and have the server send back a message to indicate it received the ping
service_worker.js:
import io from 'socket.io-client';

const socket = io('https://jwatch-9aa4eb37612b.herokuapp.com'); // Replace with your Socket.IO server URL

console.log("SOCKET");

socket.io.on('ping', () => {
    console.log("Server Ping");
})

socket.on('pingClient', (message) => {
    console.log(`Received confirmation from server: ${message}`);
    servermessage = message;
    console.log('Server Message: ' + servermessage);
});

Server Code :
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const cors = require('cors');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

const { Server } = require('socket.io');
const io = new Server(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "*",
        methods: ['GET', 'POST']
    }
});

app.use(cors());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send("Server is Running");
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log("user connected");

    socket.on('pingServer', () => {
        socket.emit('pingClient', `Received from Server on ${Date()}`);
    });

    socket.on('ping', () =>{
        socket.emit('pingClient', `Received from Server on ${Date()}`);
    })
});

server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`);
});

How do I get the client to log the ping event from the server? The error I receive is "service_worker.js:1 Event handler of 'offline' event must be added on the initial evaluation of worker script."

This library is for a web site service worker, so it's probably incompatible with an extension service worker. As for the error, you can suppress it by adding self.onoffline = console.log;

@wOxxOm What could I do for a workaround?

I don't know, try the suggestion in my comment.
